# Removing every character in .txt that isn't enclosed by pipes ( | ) OR where the line starts with #

Tags: unix, sed

I've got a bunch of .txt files that look like this:

```
 # title: I Got Stripes  
 # artist: Johnny Cash  
 # metre: 4/4  
 # tonic: Db  

0.000000000 silence  
0.348299319 A, intro, | Cb:maj | Db:maj | Db:maj |, (guitar)  
3.931269841 B, verse, | Db:maj | Db:maj | Ab:maj | Ab:maj |, (voice
8.662993197 | Ab:maj | Ab:maj | Db:maj | Db:maj |  
 # tonic: Eb  
78.145873015    D, modulation, | Eb:maj | Eb:maj |, (guitar)  
80.474625850    B, verse, | Eb:maj | Eb:maj | Bb:maj | Bb:maj |, (voice  
85.104784580    | Bb:maj | Bb:maj | Eb:maj | Eb:maj |
```

and I need to convert them to something like this:

```
  # title: I Got Stripes  
  # artist: Johnny Cash  
  # metre: 4/4  
  # tonic: Db  

| Cb:maj | Db:maj | Db:maj |  
| Db:maj | Db:maj | Ab:maj | Ab:maj |  
| Ab:maj | Ab:maj | Db:maj | Db:maj |  
  # tonic: Eb  
| Eb:maj | Eb:maj |  
| Eb:maj | Eb:maj | Bb:maj | Bb:maj |  
| Bb:maj | Bb:maj | Eb:maj | Eb:maj |
```

Specifically, that means:

- Every line that starts with # needs to stay exactly the same
- Every blank line (such as line 5 in my mock example) needs to stay there
- For all other lines, every character that isn't enclosed by pipes ( | ) needs to be removed

I have +/- 700 files, in different subdirectories.

I was thinking of writing a sed script, but can't quite figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/^ *#/b;s/^[^|]*//;s/[^|]*$//' filename
```

How it works:

- If the line begins with a `#` (with optional spaces before the `#`), branch to the next cycle (i.e. don't do anything)
- Remove anything from the beginning of the line to `|`
- Remove anything from the end of the line before `|`

---

If you are using BSD sed, split it up:

```
sed -e '/^ *#/b' -e 's/^[^|]*//;s/[^|]*$//;' filename
```

Comment: @jaypal why you deleted your's?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well If I had my way I would do `awk 1 file` instead of `cat file`. `:)`. Simple things should be done in simpler manner. I'm known to make things complicated. This is a much better, easier to understand and cleaner solution  then my `awk` version.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Did you know that jaypal has `awk` versions of most commonly used shell utilities?

Comment: I get following error `sed: 1: "/^ *#/b;s/^[^|]*//;s/[^ ...": undefined label ';s/^[^|]*//;s/[^|]*$//'`

Comment: @HubertLéveillé Added an alternative that should pacify BSD sed.

Comment: @HubertLéveillé Are you trying to make in-file changes? If you are using `-i` option make sure you put empty quotes around it for no backup or give a back up file name.

Comment: @jaypal No, BSD sed is too stupid to figure that the semicolon after `b` completes the command and starts a new one.  It considers everything after `b` to be a label.  Pretty dumb of it.

Comment: @jaypal I actually need to override the old file entirely. devnull's edit works to display the results on the screen, but I tried something like this `sed -e '/^ *#/b' -e 's/^[^|]*//;s/[^|]*$//;' filename > filename` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @HubertLéveillé You can't write to the same file you are editing. Do this instead `sed '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. Check your man-page to see if your `sed` supports the `-i` option which does this for you.